# Separate a multiple plot into 4 different plot

Tags: r

This snippet:

```
library(stm)
gadarian <- gadarian
K<-c(5,10,15)
temp<-textProcessor(documents=gadarian$open.ended.response,metadata=gadarian)
out <- prepDocuments(temp$documents, temp$vocab, temp$meta)
documents <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <- out$meta
set.seed(02138)
K<-c(5,10,15)
df1 <- searchK(documents, vocab, K, prevalence=~treatment + s(pid_rep), data=meta)
```

produce a plot using this command:

```
plot(df1)
```

This plot contains 4 plot insight.

How is it possible to receive them into 4 different plots with the same labels they have in the one merged plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
plot(df1$results$K,df1$results$heldout, type = "b", 
     xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Held-out Likelihood",
     main="Held-out Likelihood")

plot(df1$results$K,df1$results$semcoh, type = "b", 
     xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Semantic Coherence",
     main="Semantic Coherence")

plot(df1$results$K,df1$results$residual, type = "b", 
     xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Residual",
     main="Residual")

plot(df1$results$K,df1$results$lbound, type = "b", 
     xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Lower Bound",
     main="Lower Bound")
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
plot(df1$results$K, df1$results$heldout, type = "p", main = "Held-Out Likelihood", 
    xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Held-Out Likelihood", ask = TRUE)
lines(df1$results$K, df1$results$heldout, lty = 1, col = 1)
```

[image]

```
plot(df1$results$K, df1$results$residual, type = "p", main = "Residuals", 
    xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Residuals", ask = TRUE)
lines(df1$results$K, df1$results$residual, lty = 1, col = 1)
```

[image]

```
plot(df1$results$K, df1$results$semcoh, type = "p", main = "Semantic Coherence", 
      xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Semantic Coherence", ask = TRUE)
lines(df1$results$K, df1$results$semcoh, lty = 1, col = 1)
```

[image]

```
plot(df1$results$K, df1$results$lbound, type = "p", main = "Lower Bound", 
     xlab = "Number of Topics (K)", ylab = "Lower Bound", ask = TRUE)
lines(df1$results$K, df1$results$lbound, lty = 1, col = 1)
```

[image]